# React Native Animated image rorate play and pause

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to make it possible to stop the rotation of the image and start the rotation from that position. Thank you.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {StyleSheet, View, Animated, Image, Easing} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  constructor() {

    super()

    this.RotateValueHolder = new Animated.Value(0);

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.StartImageRotateFunction();

  }

  StartImageRotateFunction() {

    this.RotateValueHolder.setValue(0)

    Animated.timing(
        this.RotateValueHolder,
        {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 3000,
            easing: Easing.linear
        }
    ).start(() => this.StartImageRotateFunction())

  }

  render() {

    const RotateData = this.RotateValueHolder.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
    })

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Animated.Image
                style={{
                    width: 250,
                    height: 230,
                    transform: [{rotate: RotateData}]
                }}
                source={{uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Butterfly.png'}}/>

        </View>
      );
   }  
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {

    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this would be to call `RotateData.stopAnimation()`

Example snack: https://snack.expo.io/B1mPsdt_Q

Relevant code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(
      this.rotate,
      { toValue: 1, duration: 3000 }
    ).start()

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.rotate.stopAnimation(e => {
        console.log('animation stopped', e)
      })
    }, 2000)

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      Animated.timing(
        this.rotate,
        { toValue: 1, duration: 2000}
      ).start()
    }, 4000)
  }
```

As you can see, I have set the rotation to run for 10 seconds and a timeout to stop it after 2 seconds. If you open the snack you will see that the item stops rotating as desired. After 4 seconds the animation will resume from it's current position when called without any added configuration.

Also important to note is that the animation stops on the current value, and `stopAnimation()` accepts a callback as an argument and that callback will be passed the value of the animation at the moment it is stopped.